# OWL: Abstract classes , anonymous nodes, Regular Expressions

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

When defining an Ontology using OWL, is there a way to say that a class

- should always be an Anonymous Node
  (no rdf:about="...") e.g. <my:FamousQuote/>
- is abstract and any Instance of this class should
  always use a subClass

(edited here:)

- that a DataTypeProperty should match a regular expression ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OWL (in general) is about entailments given a set of RDF, not about validation (especially with regards to structure).

- There is no way in OWL 1.1 to know if a node is anonymous or not. OWL 2 does not seem to support this either (via a `owl:Restriction`, for example).
- For the abstract class requirement, [this post](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-owl/2007-September/003823.html) on the Protege mailing list has some ideas on how to do this.
- OWL 1.1 `DatatypeProperties` do not support "validation" of a given statement's object. OWL 2 has [datatype facets](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-owl2-rdf-based-semantics-20090421/#Facet_Names) (including `xsd:pattern`) which you could potentially use.

*Update:* You may be able to use [SPIN](http://spinrdf.org/) to query the graph structure and contents in order to infer new triples.

Answer (score 0):

Defining A as abstract class using following OWL syntax

A subClassOf (unionOf [B, C]) and (disjoint[B, C])